# Conditionally select a named range in VBA then copy to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to choose between named ranges based on a condition than copy the data to another worksheet. MyRange1 or MyRange2.

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub copy_it()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("MyRange1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Equipment Details").Range("A1") 'Like this
end sub
```

What I want do is put the chosen range into a variable (IE choice), then pass it into the .range command like this.

```
Sub copy_it()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Choice").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Equipment Details").Range("A1")
end sub
```

Comment: Hey Perry, for variables we can't use double inverted comma.  Ex: Range(Choice).Copy

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Sub copy_it()
    Dim choice
    choice = "Range1"
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range(choice).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Equipment Details").Range("A1")
end sub
```